# iOS: Is it possible to programmatically disconnect a call?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Is it possible to disconnect a call programmatically? I know call kit can be used to make VOIP calls/ block users but is it possible to install an app and lets say user is busy and just by enabling a flag in the app just send them all to voicemail or disconnect without user interaction?

**UPDATE**

Someone marked the question as too broad. It is a simple question, is it possible to 'Programmatically disconnect a call'. not sure how this can be marked as too broad.

Comment: If the user is busy they could just enable do not disturb with a single tap in the control center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Stack Overflow says my answer is too short... what else can I say? I make iOS apps since 2012, I know which APIs there are. It's hard to prove that something doesn't exist, other than saying "I would know it if it were possible."

Comment: "what else can I say?" Don't answer questions that should clearly be closed as too broad.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: why is it too broad? You cannot disconnect a call programmatically on a non-jailbroken device. A simple answer to a simple question. Why do you think the question is bad?

Comment: BTW, the question contains "enough detail to identify an adequate answer", so it cannot be too broad. The quote is from the close-vote dialog.

Comment: @Michael Thank you! that answers my question. I'm glad at least you were able to 'understand' my question and it wasn't 'too broad'.